# Android Jenkins Deployment

Tags: android, jenkins

I am looking at ways to automate Android build deployment for Beta/QA Testers via Jenkins. Are there any solutions out there that will allow me to deploy my android apk via jenkins to a test harness of some sort, from where my QA and beta testers  could download and install the application ?

Answer (score 3):

Everything almost work out of the box for Android on Jenkins now. You can :

- use the Android Emulator Plugin and perform your tests using ant debug test
- get emma coverage and reporting (you must export the emma reports as artefacts) using ant emma installd test
- you can even get your unit test reports inside jenkins (export the reports as artefacts as well) using a special test runner : either the [missing Android Test Runner](http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/) or [Zutubi test runner](https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report).
- you can get lint analysis and results thanks to the Lint Plugin for Jenkins as well.

Everything that can be done with ant will also work with maven for more industrial configurations.

We are actually working on a better integration of other testing technologies and a better intregration with Sonar, this topic should get some progress during 2013.

Comment: 1 up for the super quick answer.. I was typing the first line itself :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking for deployment solutions. Are there any test harnesses that can be used in conjunction with Jenkins that allow me to distribute my application internally. Production distro offcourse will be shipped to the market place ?

Comment: This comment is not very clear. Looking for what kind of deployment solution ? A market store ? An internal ftp/http server upload ? An email with the apk attached ? ---- What do you mean by test harnesses ? You must write your own test suites and there are many technologies you can use for that: robolectric, robotium, ui automator, calabash, monkey runner, etc. I suggested you a way to use standard android testing framework for jenkins, but you can test your app using alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

For distributing your APK to beta testers, you can try services like [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/) or [Google Play alpha/beta distribution](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#alpha-beta), both of which have [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hockeyapp+Plugin) [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin) to upload your builds.

By using those services and their SDKs in your app, you automatically get usage statistics and crash reports from your testers.